# Цикл foreach против Iterable.foreach в Java 8: что лучше?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-8, java-stream, java-faq

Что из следующего является лучше практикой в Java 8?

Java 8:

```
list.forEach(e -> e.operation);
```

Java 7:

```
for (E e : list) {
    e.operation;
}
```

У меня есть много циклов, которые могут быть упрощены с помощью лямбд, но есть ли какие-то реальные преимущества от использования `Iterator.foreach`?

Улучшится ли производительность и читабельность кода?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения производительности нет никаких обещанных заметных преимуществ от использования `Iterable.forEach` по сравнению с `foreach`.

Согласно официальным [javadoc на `Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

> Performs the given action on the contents of the Iterable, **in the
>   order elements** occur when iterating, until all elements have been
>   processed or the action throws an exception.

Т.е. понятно, что не будет никакого явного параллелизма. Добавление параллелизма будет нарушением LSP.

Про читабельность кода: вы вероятно используете `Iterable.foreach` только с короткими однострочными лямбдами. Если "тело" лямбды увеличится, то читабельность скорее всего будет хуже, чем в цикле.

---

**Примечание:** этот ответ работает при использовании `StreamAPI`. Если используется только `java.util.Iterable`, то этот ответ перестает работать.

У вас будет сильное преимущество при параллельной обработке большого количества данных. Если вы хотите, что бы цикл выполнялся параллельно, то вы должны использовать такую конструкцию:

```
list.parallelStream().forEach(e -> e.operation);
```

Однако использование не-параллельных стримов при обработке малого количества данных будет дольше, чем `foreach` и циклы.

---

**Вывод:**

1. Между `Iterable.foreach` и циклом `foreach` в производительности разницы нет.
2. Если тело лямбды будет небольшим, то лучше использовать `Iterable.foreach`.
3. Если вы хотите прирост в производительности, то вам лучше использовать `parallelStream.foreach()`.